# Symfony2 API subdomain and local testing with /api uri prefix

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, fosrestbundle

small question.

Currently I'm working in DEV Mode on localhost.
There I call the API like this.

`http://localhost/project/web/app_dev.php/api/get_all`

And now I want to add a detection for api subdomain so that I can use the uri above and this one below.

`http://api.example.org/get_all`

Is this possible? And if yes: Can you give me a idea how this can work?
Maybe via Request-Rewrite in `.htaccess`? (Simple)
Or (Complex) via rewriting request on kernel event?

I'm using FOSUserBundle with this `routing.yml`.

```
api:
    resource: "@ApiBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /api
    defaults: {_format: json}
```

Comment: I'd recommend mapping dev domains directly to live domains. So using `api.localhost` or something test your api.example.org domain.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this as described in [How to Match a Route Based on the Host](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html).

```
api:
    resource: "@ApiBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    path:     /
    host:     "api.example.com"
    defaults: {_format: json}
```

Or use [PHP routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#routing-examples) to vary the route based on the environment.

But I wouldn't recommend either option.

Comment: Ok but with your other answer the best thing to do is to use for example: `api.project.localhost` and `project.localhost`? Or do you mean it makes sense that I have a domain parameter in `parameters.yml` and there I set on productive environment the `project.org` and on development environment `localhost`? And in routing.yml I'm using this parameter to have routing for api and default domain? Or whats your `perfekt way / best practise`? :-) I'd like to do it right and professional ;-)

Comment: The best way is one testing domain for every production domain. And don't reference any domains in your configuration. You'll get the fewest surprises that way.

Comment: So the best would be to use a installation for `api.` and one for `www.`?

Comment: Yes. That's what I would do. If you have to manage two domains on production, I don't think you gain very much by having one development domain.